# ASP Classic on IIS7 (Windows7 Ulitmate) is not working?

Tags: iis, asp

My IIS working OK and it show .asp files but ASP code not working...
When I direct error to browser from IIS, I get following message on my page

> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. 
>   If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Looks due to some reason I don't running ASP code part.

In IIS, **Authentication** section, I added specific user which is **Admin**.

Under **Turn Off Windows features on or off**, 
**IIS** --> **Web Management Tools** --> **IIS Management Console** is Enabled.

Under **WordWideWeb Services** --> **Application Development Features** --> **ASP and ISAPI Extentions** Enabled.

Comment: Does classic ASP work/supported in Windows7 64 bit environment?
If yes, do I need to install any special ODBC driver to connect?

Comment: If you put a text file or simple html file in the target IIS folder can you access it via the browser?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things which may help:

1. Make sure that the default document is set correctly - index.asp is not part of the standard setup for IIS7 (in IIS Manager, click on your website and you should see a Default Document icon)
2. Try switching on the feature to send ASP debugging info to the browser (in IIS Manager, double-click the ASP icon, click the "+" next to "Debugging Properties", and set "Send Errors To Browser" to True)

If you have IIS setup correctly. the ASP page should at least run the code and give you some error information back, which hopefully will lead you to resolving your issue.

Comment: When I send error to browser, it shows following on page..  "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error" When I click here link it leads to MS IIS help page.

Comment: I also added a very simple test.asp file. It is not running any asp code.

Comment: That looks like the standard IIS script error message. Have you put the .asp files under wwwroot or have you created a new folder? If it's a new folder then it will need to have permissions for IIS_IUSRS on your local machine.

Comment: Also under Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off, make sure you have ASP (as well as ASP.NET) and Static Content selected - they're under IIS, World Wide Web Services...

Comment: And as techie007 says above, make sure you can display a simple static html file, e.g. index.htm, before you go much further

Comment: I can display html file and also .asp with html tags only. It stops where asp related code start. IIS_IUSRS are added in permission foles folder security setting.

Comment: I created new folder and created virtual directory.